# Can not deploy ARM template of Azure App Service with Linux that has mounted storage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-files

We are trying to deploy Azure Linux App Service, that also has mounted storage. Here's our ARM template

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "Environment": {
            "type": "String",
            "allowedValues": [
                "dev",
                "stg",
                "prd"
            ]
        },
        "Region": {
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
                "eu",
                "we"
            ]
        },
        "MagentoMediaFileShareName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "StorageAccountName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "StorageAccountAccessKey": {
            "type": "securestring"
        },
        "MagentoMediaMountPath": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "/var/www/html/pub/external_media"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "Location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "ResourcePrefix": "[format('ariva-{0}-{1}-magento', parameters('Environment'), parameters('Region'))]",
        "WebSiteName": "[concat(variables('ResourcePrefix'), '-web')]",
        "ServicePlanId": "[format('/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/ariva-{1}-{2}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/ariva-{1}-{2}-asp', subscription().subscriptionId,  parameters('Environment'), parameters('Region'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[variables('WebSiteName')]",
            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
            "kind": "app,linux,container",
            "properties": {
                "enabled": true,
                "hostNameSslStates": [
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(variables('WebSiteName'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "hostType": "Standard"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(variables('WebSiteName'), '.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "hostType": "Repository"
                    }
                ],
                "serverFarmId": "[variables('ServicePlanId')]",
                "reserved": true,
                "isXenon": false,
                "hyperV": false,
                "siteConfig": {
                    "numberOfWorkers": 1,
                    "linuxFxVersion": "DOCKER|mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/staticsite:latest",
                    "acrUseManagedIdentityCreds": false,
                    "alwaysOn": false,
                    "http20Enabled": false,
                    "functionAppScaleLimit": 0,
                    "minimumElasticInstanceCount": 1
                },
                "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                "clientCertEnabled": false,
                "clientCertMode": "Required",
                "hostNamesDisabled": false,
                "customDomainVerificationId": "1071794BD68C78EC0A4569F03C034F6E1B21BD4E6D35725D99523AC00AE12AA1",
                "containerSize": 0,
                "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
                "keyVaultReferenceIdentity": "SystemAssigned",
                "httpsOnly": false,
                "redundancyMode": "None",
                "storageAccountRequired": false
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('WebSiteName'), '/ftp')]",
            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('WebSiteName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "allow": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('WebSiteName'), '/scm')]",
            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('WebSiteName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "allow": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('WebSiteName'), '/web')]",
            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('WebSiteName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "numberOfWorkers": 1,
                "defaultDocuments": [
                    "Default.htm",
                    "Default.html",
                    "Default.asp",
                    "index.htm",
                    "index.html",
                    "iisstart.htm",
                    "default.aspx",
                    "index.php",
                    "hostingstart.html"
                ],
                "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.0",
                "linuxFxVersion": "DOCKER|mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/staticsite:latest",
                "requestTracingEnabled": false,
                "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
                "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2019",
                "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
                "acrUseManagedIdentityCreds": false,
                "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
                "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
                "publishingUsername": "[concat('$', variables('WebSiteName'))]",
                "azureStorageAccounts": {
                    "magento-media": {
                        "type": "AzureFiles",
                        "accountName": "[parameters('StorageAccountName')]",
                        "shareName": "[parameters('MagentoMediaFileShareName')]",
                        "mountPath": "[parameters('MagentoMediaMountPath')]",
                        "accessKey": "[parameters('StorageAccountAccessKey')]"
                    }
                },
                "scmType": "None",
                "use32BitWorkerProcess": true,
                "webSocketsEnabled": true,
                "alwaysOn": true,
                "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
                "virtualApplications": [
                    {
                        "virtualPath": "/",
                        "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                        "preloadEnabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "loadBalancing": "LeastRequests",
                "experiments": {
                    "rampUpRules": []
                },
                "autoHealEnabled": false,
                "vnetRouteAllEnabled": false,
                "vnetPrivatePortsCount": 0,
                "localMySqlEnabled": false,
                "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
                    {
                        "ipAddress": "Any",
                        "action": "Allow",
                        "priority": 1,
                        "name": "Allow all",
                        "description": "Allow all access"
                    }
                ],
                "scmIpSecurityRestrictions": [
                    {
                        "ipAddress": "Any",
                        "action": "Allow",
                        "priority": 1,
                        "name": "Allow all",
                        "description": "Allow all access"
                    }
                ],
                "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain": false,
                "http20Enabled": true,
                "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
                "scmMinTlsVersion": "1.0",
                "ftpsState": "AllAllowed",
                "preWarmedInstanceCount": 0,
                "functionAppScaleLimit": 0,
                //"healthCheckPath": "/health_check.php",
                "functionsRuntimeScaleMonitoringEnabled": false,
                "minimumElasticInstanceCount": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('WebSiteName'), '/', variables('WebSiteName'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('WebSiteName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "siteName": "[variables('WebSiteName')]",
                "hostNameType": "Verified"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If we execute this exact template, we will receive the following error

```json
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Required parameter AccessKey is missing.",
        "details": [
            {
                "message": "Required parameter AccessKey is missing."
            },
            {
                "code": "BadRequest"
            },
            {}
        ]
    }
}
```

We receive the same error if we have storage manually mounted through portal and try to change the configurations or add deployment slots.

As soon as I remove the mounted storage configuration, everything works just fine.

We need to have this in our DevOps pipeline, it's not acceptable that we unmount-remount the storage manually before and after the deployments. That would cause major issues and downtime. What can we do to overcome the issue?

**UPDATE 1**

I've tried to create a totally separate web app and storage account all manually. As soon as I hooked the storage mount and tried to enable health checks for instance, I got the same error. I think there's a bug in Azure.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the template that deploys the dependent storage account

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "Environment": {
            "type": "String",
            "allowedValues": [
                "dev",
                "stg",
                "prd"
            ]
        },
        "Region": {
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
                "eu",
                "we"
            ]
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "Location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "StorageAccountName": "[format('ariva{0}{1}magentostorage', parameters('Environment'), parameters('Region'))]",
        "MagentoMediaFileShareName": "magento-media"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[variables('StorageAccountName')]",
            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "kind": "StorageV2",
            "properties": {
                "allowCrossTenantReplication": true,
                "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_2",
                "allowBlobPublicAccess": true,
                "allowSharedKeyAccess": true,
                "networkAcls": {
                    "resourceAccessRules": [],
                    "bypass": "AzureServices",
                    "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                    "ipRules": [],
                    "defaultAction": "Allow"
                },
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
                "encryption": {
                    "services": {
                        "file": {
                            "keyType": "Account",
                            "enabled": true
                        },
                        "blob": {
                            "keyType": "Account",
                            "enabled": true
                        }
                    },
                    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                },
                "accessTier": "Hot"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('StorageAccountName'), '/default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('StorageAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "properties": {
                "changeFeed": {
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "restorePolicy": {
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "containerDeleteRetentionPolicy": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "days": 7
                },
                "cors": {
                    "corsRules": []
                },
                "deleteRetentionPolicy": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "days": 7
                },
                "isVersioningEnabled": false
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('StorageAccountName'), '/default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('StorageAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "properties": {
                "shareDeleteRetentionPolicy": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "days": 7
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('StorageAccountName'), '/default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('StorageAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "cors": {
                    "corsRules": []
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('StorageAccountName'), '/default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('StorageAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "cors": {
                    "corsRules": []
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('StorageAccountName'), '/default/', variables('MagentoMediaFileShareName'))]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices', variables('StorageAccountName'), 'default')]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('StorageAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "accessTier": "TransactionOptimized",
                "shareQuota": 5120,
                "enabledProtocols": "SMB"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "MagentoMediaFileShareName": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[variables('MagentoMediaFileShareName')]"
        },
        "StorageAccountName": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[variables('StorageAccountName')]"
        },
        "StorageAccountAccessKey": {
            "type": "securestring",
            "value": "[listKeys(variables('StorageAccountName'), '2019-04-01').keys[0].value]"
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 3 - temporary workaround**

We were able to find a temporary workaround. Instead of deploying the file mount through the ARM template, we've removed that bit from ARM template, after, we use the following build step in our DevOps pipeline to mount the storage through azure CLI

```
 - task: AzureCLI@2
   displayName: 'Attach media volume'
   inputs:
     azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}'
     scriptType: pscore
     scriptLocation: inlineScript
     inlineScript: |
       az webapp config storage-account add `
         --resource-group ${{ parameters.resourceGroup }} `
         --name "$(WebSiteName)" `
         --access-key "$(StorageAccountAccessKey)" `
         --custom-id magento-media `
         --storage-type AzureFiles `
         --share-name "$(MagentoMediaFileShareName)" `
         --account-name "$(StorageAccountName)" `
         --mount-path "/var/www/html/pub/external_media"
```

This doesn't solve the problem of course.

1. Doing so, ARM template will essentially remove the mount and then it will be deployed by the script, causing downtime
2. When mount is in place, we still can't change any of the WebApp properties through the portal and we will get the error that AccessKey is missing

Comment: How is the security for the storage account configured? Also just to confirm, when `//"healthCheckPath": "/health_check.php",` is commented, your template deploys but when it isn't, you get the error?

Comment: @RyanHill-MSFT we are deploying storage in another ARM template. We do not have any specific security settings. I've updated the post with the storage ARM template that we use. Then, we output the AccessKey and supply it as an input parameter for this deployment. 
As for the health-check, it's not configured yet. It doesn't change the behaviour when we use it, we still receive failure of AccessKey with and without health checks. The reason I mentioned health checks is that when you mount the storage through GUI and the try to add health check then the same error is raised.

Comment: In the Azure Portal, does the storage account you set up have access keys? I didn't run into the same issue you did when [mounting the storage account to the app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=portal&pivots=container-linux).

Comment: Your settings should look similar to https://i.imgur.com/Qbwl5cb.png

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan. After changing the ARM template according to the below suggestions everything worked as far as the storage mount is concerned))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`azureStorageAccounts` is not part of [Microsoft.Web sites/config 2020-12-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2020-12-01/sites/config-web?tabs=json) however it is under [Microsoft.Web sites 2020-12-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2020-12-01/sites?tabs=json#SiteConfig) `SiteConfig` property. This may be the reason accessKey wasn't found, wasn't uploaded. I would move `azureStorageAccounts` under `siteConfig`

Comment: Thanks Ryan. You are actually right. This answers my question partially. The problem is when you export WebApp as ARM template it provides a different API version 2021-01-15 which is not available in the Microsoft documentation. The version that is available is 2020-12-01, and I simply replaced the value in the exported template with that. Which, obviously didn't work as the schema was different. How could we address this situation?

Comment: You could use the [ARM template tool test kit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/test-toolkit). If I'm not mistaken, the linters used in the [ARM](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msazurermtools.azurerm-vscode-tools) and [Bicep](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-bicep) VS Code Extensions utilizes this.

Comment: That’s true. Linter did help out a bit. But the main problem I see is that when you export WebApp ARM template it does not work out of the box. Further, it references an API version that’s at least not documented, or perhaps even not existent and linter complains about that version

Comment: I'll see what I can find out with regards to doc updates related to API version releases.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that'd be great!

Comment: The docs are currently being updated; however, I don't have an ETA of when it'll be complete though.

Comment: That's really great! Thanks for the update. I hope the json schema will also be published so that VS Code extension recognizes it.

Comment: is there any update on this I just ran into this error but with Terraform not ARM